# Roulette complex question

Tags: probability

I have a complex situation that I don't know how to solve.
So I made a program that simulates roulette spins, and makes statistics from the numbers.
For example:
From 25 000 spins the program calculates that the biggest gap for the first 12 numbers is for example 190. Now my question is, that if I spin 25 000 more, what is the probability that from the second 25 000 spins the biggest gap for the first 12 numbers is 190 again?

Comment: What do you mean by "the biggest gap for the first 12 numbers"?

Comment: For example 190 was the number that the first 12 numbers (1-12) were not spinned in a row.

Comment: So, at some some point you spun a number between 1 and 12, and then it was 190 spins before you got a number between 1 and 12 again?

Comment: Yes, and that's important that 190 was the BIGGEST gap. There can be a 189 gap too.

Comment: I just want the program to output a percentage that what was the probability to that. Or maybe the question is misleading... I can put it this way: What is the probability if I spin 25000, and the biggest gap for the first 12 numbers is 190?

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, then ask Michael Shackleford on his Wizard of Odds website.  http://wizardofodds.com/ask-the-wizard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a sequence of $N = 25000$ independent Bernoulli trials, where I'll consider a "success" to be a spin not from 1 to 12.  In each trial the probability of success is $p$, and the probability of failure is $q=1-p$.  Consider the distribution of (success) runs of length $r$, where we say a run of length $r$ occurs at trial number $j$, $r \le j \le N$, if trials number $j-r+1$ to $j$ are successes but a run of length $r$ 
does not occur on any of $j-r+1$ to $j-1$.  Thus in the sequence $SSFSSSS$ (where S denotes success and F failure) we have runs of length $2$ occurring at trials $2$, $5$ and $7$.  Let  $f_r(n)$ the probability that the first run of length
$r$ occurs at trial $n$.  The probability that there is no run of length $r$ in
$N$ trials is thus $Q_r = 1 - \sum_{n=1}^N f_r(n)$.  Since if there is 
a run of length $r$ there are also runs of all lower lengths, $$Q_r - Q_{r-1}
= \sum_{n=1}^N \left(f_{r-1}(n) - f_r(n)\right)$$ 
is the probability that the longest run has length $r$.

Now  the generating function of the $f_r(n)$ is
$$ F_r(s) = \sum_{n=r}^\infty f_r(n) s^n = \dfrac{p^r s^r(1-ps)}{1-s+qp^r s^{r+1}}$$
Thus the generating function of $f_{r-1}(n)-f_r(n)$ is
$ G_r(s) = F_{r-1}(s) - F_r(s)$.
From this we can calculate the probability of the longest run having length $r$
as $\sum_{n=1}^N g_n$ where $G_r(s) = \sum_{j=0}^\infty g_j s^j$.

As 
KSmarts remarked, for your case with $r = 190$ this probability is going to be extremely small.  If you continued your trials indefinitely, the expected number of trials until the first run of length $r$ would be
$(1 - p^r)/(q p^r)$, and with $r = 190$ and $p = 13/19$ this is
approximately $6.52 \times 10^{31}$.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you are using an American-style Roulette wheel, with 38 slots numbered 1-36 and two zeroes, then the chance of getting a number between 1 and 12 (which I'll call "low numbers") on any particular spin is $\frac{12}{38}=\frac{6}{19}\approx0.316$. Then the number of spins between low numbers is a geometrically distributed random variable with parameter $p=\frac{6}{19}$.

Taking a single trial, where you spin until you get a low number, the chance of it taking exactly $190$ spins is
$\left(1-\frac{6}{19}\right)^{190}\left(\frac{6}{19}\right)$,
which is, in technical terms, really friggin' small. It's approximately $1.5\times10^{-32}$. If we were each to randomly select one kilogram of matter from the (discretely-divided) sun, it would be more likely that we picked the same $1$kg than that this roulette test would fail $190$ times in a row. Granted, you spun $25000$ times, during which you would have gotten thousands of low numbers, and thus thousands of chances to wait, but it is still really unlikely. This makes me suspect that either your program is flawed, or I have misunderstood your question.

As to the general problem of the largest number of consecutive failures in $n$ trials, I don't know the solution offhand. I will continue working on and searching for it and will update this answer, but I would like to hear your response to my above observation as well.

Comment: I just made up the numbers, i'll run a test with my program to get realistc values

Comment: Okay i got 30 for the biggest gap in 25000 spins for the low numbers. Could you explain why is the formula like that? Like why is it needed to sqrt(190) etc

Comment: @Javexify What do you mean? There is no square root in the formula. In this case, $1-\frac{6}{19}=\frac{13}{19}$ is the probability of failure, that is, the probability of spinning a zero or a number higher than $12$. The chance of this happening $x$ times in a row is $\left(\frac{13}{19}\right)^x$. The chance of success is $\frac{6}{19}$, so the chance of the first success coming after $x$ trials is the probability of $x$ consecutive failures, times the chance of the next trial being a success.